# Slow count on empty table unexplained

Tags: oracle, performance, materialized-view, oracle-19c

My incremental materialized view refresh starting to become slower and slower. Each day there are millions of new records. So there are many deletes on the mv log table. After investigation I see one specific sql taking a lot of time which might lead to the root cause. The follow is one of the SQLs running as part of the mv refresh:

```
SQL> select dmltype$$, max(snaptime$$) from "S"."MLOG$_TABLE_202210" group by dmltype$$;

no rows selected

Elapsed: 00:00:12.68

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
      7  recursive calls
      0  db block gets
     678822  consistent gets
     678789  physical reads
      0  redo size
    438  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
     41  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      1  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
      0  sorts (memory)
      0  sorts (disk)
      0  rows processed
```

As you can see a count on this empty mv log table took 12s! (we have many like this). The reason is high physical reads. The statistics are locked in purpose (as to oracle recommendation)

```
SQL> select NUM_ROWS,BLOCKS,EMPTY_BLOCKS,AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS,LAST_ANALYZED,STATTYPE_LOCKED,STALE_STATS 
     from dba_tab_statistics 
     where table_name='MLOG$_TABLE_202210';
  NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS EMPTY_BLOCKS AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS LAST_ANAL STATT STALE_S
---------- ---------- ------------ ------------------------- --------- ----- -------
         0          0            0                         0 14-NOV-22 ALL   YES


SQL> SELECT EXTENTS, blocks, bytes
FROM dba_segments
WHERE SEGMENT_NAME = 'MLOG$_TABLE_202210';

  EXTENTS    BLOCKS     BYTES
---------- ---------- ---------- 
        18      384    3145728
```

So if the table is not in SGA it goes over all the blocks which is high due to HWM from the many deletes. Since this is all mv refresh - if I will run truncate it will break the MVs.

I would appreciate some other suggestions.

Comment: IMHO you should do something like `ALTER TABLE SHRINK SPACE` and `ALTER TABLE SHRINK SPACE COMPACT`. Amount of physical reads and consistent gets is more or less equal so I'd say whole table is in buffer cache, but 12sec is still a lot for 3GB data segment. Also note there is something like big table threshold, where Oracle "avoids" storing data blocks in buffer cache when doing FTS on table which is too big.

Comment: What is your DB version? Check Doc ID 1941137.1, Doc ID 2586653.1

Comment: Best reorg there is is a move. ALTER TABLE MLOG$_TABLE_202210 MOVE. But 384 blocks is miniscule. Hard to believe it'd take 12 seconds to read that. Have you looked at ASH data (v$active_session_history) to pinpoin the SQL and execution plan step where your time is being consumed?

Comment: What was I end up doing is `enable row movement` + `shrink space compact` + `move` - which reduced it to 0.01s.  If you want add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was I end up doing is `enable row movement` + `shrink space compact` + `move` - which reduced it to 0.01s.